# Find the roots of the function

Tags: graphing-functions

find the roots of the function when $x$ goes from $0$ to $3$?

$$f(x) = \tan(2 x) - 1$$

I tried to set $f(x)=0$ but came up with $x=28$

Comment: How did you tried?  This $x=28$ does not make sense to me in either degrees or radians.

Comment: i guess im in the wild here, but i then set tan(2x)=1 and x=1/(tan2) but it does not really make sense...

Answer (score 2):

[image]

root of trigonometric function is not unique

Comment: 1+ For the nice painting :)

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x)=0$, then $\tan(2x)=1$.

Let $\theta=2x$. For $\theta\in(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$ (the "standard" period of the tangent function), there is precisely one solution to $\tan\theta=1$: namely $\theta=\arctan(1)=\frac{\pi}{4}$. We can find all solutions to $\tan\theta=1$ by taking shifts of this by the period $\pi$: thus the solutions are precisely
$$
\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}+k\pi,\qquad k\text{ an integer}.
$$
But $\theta=2x$; so, the solutions for $x$ are what we get by dividing both sides by 2:
$$
x=\frac{\pi}{8}+\frac{k\pi}{2},\qquad k\text{ an integer}.
$$
We must find all specific solutions which lie between $0$ and $3$. These solutions are, then,
$$
x=\frac{\pi}{8},\qquad x=\frac{\pi}{8}+\frac{\pi}{2}=\frac{5\pi}{8}.
$$
All other solutions are either negative or greater than $3$.

Answer (score 0):

$\tan$ is a $\pi$-periodic function and $\tan \frac\pi 4 = 1$. Therefor
$$\begin{align*}
\tan(2x) & = 0 \\
\Leftrightarrow 2x & = \frac \pi 4 + k\pi & k\in\mathbb Z\\
\Leftrightarrow x & = \frac \pi 8 + k\frac\pi 2 & k\in\mathbb Z
\end{align*}$$
For $x\in[0,3]$ you get $k\in\{0, 1\}$ and thus
$$x \in \{\frac\pi 8, \frac{5\pi} 8\}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\tan(\theta)= 1$ when $\theta = \frac{(1+4n)\pi}{4}$ where $n$ is an integer starting at $0$, so the zeros for your problem are $2x = \frac{(1+4n)\pi}{4} = \frac{(1+4n)\pi}{8}$. For the range $x$ you gave, that would be the first two values $\frac{\pi}{8},\frac{5\pi}{8}$

Comment: You can also edit your answers, you need not delete them. Downvotes will be removed if errors are corrected. Also, $\tan$ is written $\$\text{\tan}\$$ in MathJax.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
another way to find the roots if to find intersection between f(x) and g(x)
f=tan(2x)
g=1

Answer (score -2):

Just set $f(x) = 0$, that is,

$\tan(2x) - 1 = 0 \implies \tan(2x) = 1 \implies 2x = \arctan(1) \implies x = \frac{\arctan(1)}{2} \approx 0.3927$

Comment: This gives you *a* solution; however, there are two. Also, it is poor form to go to decimals here, as this can be expressed exactly.